# Music - PLaying online radios

Tags: music, multimedia

I installed elementary OS couple of days ago and am really liking it. Thanks to the developer team for the great work.

I want to listen online radio. I have downloaded .pls and .asx files from the website of the raido station. But i am not able to open both of these files using Music app. I have also tried Video app, same thing.

Is there a way that Music app could play these files? Or should I look for another application on AppCenter.

Here is the files;

> http://listen.trancebase.fm/dsl.pls
> http://listen.trancebase.fm/dsl.asx

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can. If your existent media player isn't up to the task, one fairly universal application ([VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/)) almost certainly is.

You can install it from the AppCenter or from the terminal. To install it via the AppCenter, just search for it and click install. To do so via the terminal:

```
sudo apt install vlc
```

Then, just copy the URL to the stream you want to play and open it as a 'network stream' in VLC. I just tested it  with the exact URL you posted and it plays just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use Radiotray-NG: An Internet radio player for Linux
more info: https://github.com/ebruck/radiotray-ng
and if anyone ask how you see the icon in the systemtray:
https://www.reallinuxuser.com/how-to-show-app-indicators-on-the-system-tray-in-elementary-os/